# How to incorporate Java files in iOS

Tags: java, ios, objective-c

I have a application in which I want to incorporate Java files in my iOS app.
These Java files are wrapper classes for the Android app. I need to use the same Java classes in iOS and call methods of that Java class in iOS.

Comment: Not possible, iOS uses objective-c. This question has been asked hundreds of times on every website, a simple google search would have answered this

Answer (score 4):

You can't use Java classes in iOS the same as you can't use Objective-C classes in Android, they are different platforms with different languages.

Try to find a Objective-C / C version of the library you are trying to use or another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

As rightly said by Antonio MG, you can't import Java code into Objective-C project, the language doesn't allow that.
On the contrary Java supports native codes (C/C++) via JNI (Java Native Interfaces).